# M/S to HRD Migration aliasing

Tags: google-app-engine

I am currently preparing to migrate a Master/Slave based application over to the High Replication Datastore. The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration?hl=en) states that *"As the last step, you will make your old application ID an "alias" for the new one"* but I cannot find any functionality in the GAE dash which does this.

Can anyone explain how this step works? Is it automatic or manual? If it's automatic then how if a problem occurs do you revert back to the original app-id and remove the alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original URL of your app will still work but App Engine processes your requests with the new app instead of the old one. So ***old-app.appspot.com*** works like ***new-app.appspot.com***.

This is done automatically at the end of the migration process.

For problems you will need to contact Google through a production ticket.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm trying to establish is whether if anything goes wrong after the migration process, can you remove the alias to go back to the original M/S ID? It is a bit worrying to me that I have no control over this part of the migration.